# Horizontal and vertical scroll on table

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="tableDiv">
    <table class="calTable" id="calTable">
        <thead id="calTableThd">
            <tr>
                <th ></th>
                <th ng-repeat="headers in headerList">{{headers}}</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="rows in peopleList">
                <td><span>{{rows[0].name}}</span></td>
                <td ng-repeat="cellList in rows">
                    <div><input type="checkbox"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have a table with headers. Number of rows and columns both are dynamic.
I want a horizontal scroll with fixed first column on left and a vertical scroll with fixed header on top.
Please help.

Comment: are you using angular or angularjs?

Comment: i am using angularjs

Comment: You can use https://jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/bzuasLcz/3/, This is using jquery without using extra plugins or libraries

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for fixed header without jquery... 
You can think in same way for fixed first column. Sorry didn't had enough time to write all the code.

You just have to think in context of first `<th>` of `<thead>` and first `<td>` of `<tr>`..

https://jsfiddle.net/Jayraj178/ebckjahm/13/